# How to JOIN on columns with same name?

Tags: sql, sqlite, union, full-outer-join

I have tables `T1` and `T2`. Both have columns `ID`, `X` and `Y`. In addition, `T1` has another column `Z` and `T2` has another column `A`. `ID` is primary key. `X` is calculated from `ID` (so if `ID` matches, also `X` matches). Column `Y` exists in both tables but content is not the same relative to `ID`. `A` and `Z` do not have anything to do with each other.

`T1`:

| ID | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X1 | Y1 | Z1 |
| 2 | X2 | Y2 | Z2 |

`T2`:

| ID | X | Y | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | X2 | Y3 | A1 |
| 3 | X3 | Y4 | A2 |

I want a query which returns a record that contains all data from both tables and fills in `NULL` whenever a field has no data.

Result:

| ID | X | T1Y | T2Y | Z | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X1 | Y1 | NULL | Z1 | NULL |
| 2 | X2 | Y2 | Y3 | Z2 | A1 |
| 3 | X3 | NULL | Y4 | NULL | A2 |

My SQLite version does not support `RIGHT JOIN` or `FULL JOIN`. I tried :

```
SELECT T1.ID, T2.ID
FROM   T1 
       LEFT JOIN T2
          ON T1.ID = T2.ID
UNION
SELECT T1.ID, T2.ID
FROM   T2 
       LEFT JOIN T1 
          ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE  T1.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

But got:

| ID | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Null |
| 2 | 2 |
| NULL | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can phrase the `full join` with `union all` like so:

```
select t1.id, t1.x, t1.y t1y, t2.y t2y, t1.z, t2.a
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
union all
select t2.id, t2.x, t1.y, t2.y, t1.z, t2.a
from t2
left join t1 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id is null
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/luWCC-Ny)**

Answer (score 2):

Since version [3.39.0](https://sqlite.org/changes.html) SQLite supports `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.ID, T2.ID) ID,
       COALESCE(T1.X, T2.X) X,
       T1.Y T1Y,
       T2.Y T2Y,
       T1.Z,
       T2.A
FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN T2
ON T2.ID = T1.ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/n-5W9vlD).

Comment: Obviously this works, thanks! Unfortunately a lot of tools and APIs are still stuck at older versions of SQLite.